# NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error: encoding issue

Tags: iphone, ios, json, nsjsonserialization

In my code, I download a `JSON` data encoded in `UTF8`, which is the ideal to work with `NSJSONSerialization`, but when I get the parsed object, it's full of encoding problems such as:

> "Jo\U00e3o e Maria - Ca\U00e7adores de Bruxas"

(it must be "João e Maria - Caçadores de Bruxas"). Tried to reencode it in ASCII, Unicode and others with no success:

```
NSData *downloadedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL cachePolicy:cachePolicy timeoutInterval:timeoutInterval] returningResponse:NULL error:&error];
NSDictionary *serializedDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

EDIT: When I print using this, it shows correctly:

```
NSLog(@"Test: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloadedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Comment: so there is no issue anymore?

Comment: How are you checking the parsed data?  If you are using NSLog, it may be printing out the escaped characters such as \U00e3 for ã.

Comment: Thanks, I was testing it in NSLog because I still don't have a UI to work with, but inside a UILabel it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are UTF8 encoded characters. The format is correct, put them on a `UILabel` or something and they'll appear as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the polished text itself try

```
NSString * s = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[<your_string> UTF8String]];
```